# Gradle dependency not shared with dependent module

Tags: android, gradle, koin

## Context

I have two modules in my project:

- Java/Kotlin module `common`
- Android/Kotlin module `app`

`common` depends on [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/), which is a Kotlin library for dependency injection:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.koin:koin-core:1.0.2'
}
```

Usage example:

```
class MyPresenter: KoinComponent {
  ...
}
```

`app` does not depend on the Koin library because I do not need to inject anything in the Android code, all the injections are in the common code (presenters, interceptors, etc).

But `app` depends on `common`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':common')
}
```

Usage example:

```
class MyFragment {
  private val presenter = MyPresenter()
}
```

---

## Problem

I can compile `common`, I can run unit tests in `common`, but when I try to compile `app` I get this error:

> Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make
>   sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
>       class xxx.common.presenter.MyPresenter, unresolved supertypes: org.koin.standalone.KoinComponent

When I run `./gradlew :app:dependencies`

```
debugCompileClasspath
+--- project :common
debugRuntimeClasspath
+--- project :common
|    +--- org.koin:koin-core:1.0.2
```

The dependency is in the `runtime` configuration, but is missing from the `compile` configuration.

---

## What I have tried so far:

Obviously I don't want to declare the Koin dependency in `app` so I have tried several things:

Change Koin dependency for `api`:

```
dependencies {
  api 'org.koin:koin-core:1.0.2'
}
```

**Not working** - I get the exact same dependency tree as with `implementation`.

Change project dependency configuration:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(path: ':common', configuration: `compile`)
}
```

**Not working** - I wasn't sure of this one but I was hoping it would get the dependencies of `common` in `compile` configuration.

Change Koin dependency for `compile`:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.koin:koin-core:1.0.2'
}
```

**Working!** The dependency appears in the `debugCompileClasspath` and I am able to run the `app`.

---

## Questions

Now I am confused:

- As `app` does not use Koin directly, I though it would not need the dependency. Why does it? Is it because the static type of `MyPresenter` is `KoinComponent`?
- I thought `api` was the same than the deprecated `compile`. It seems not.
- Is there another way other than using the deprecated `compile`?

Answer (score 2):

- Because you make Koin types appear in the APIs of common, then consumers of common need to know about the Koin types. They effectively become API.
- The `api` configuration is what you should use and should work
- The most likely explanation is that between the Android/Kotlin project on one side and the Java/Kotlin project on the other side have a different definition of what `api` is, how the consumable configuration `apiElements` is built or accessed or ...

To debug that, I would recommend creating a simple project that reproduces the problem and that can be shared as there might be a bug behind that in the android or kotlin plugin.